# TS path aliases not resolved using tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin in Webpack 5.0.0-beta.18

Tags: typescript, webpack

This is my [poject repo](https://gitlab.com/squishypandadev/project_gryphon) where I'm facing issues. I had to use beta version of webpack for top level await support; thanks to electron. Webpack config is written in Typescript. Plugin is loaded in the resolve section of the config. Run `build:ts` to exec webpack.

When did exec webpack, I got this error message:

> Can't resolve '#passage' in '`${project_path}`\project_gryphon\src\renderer'
> Tried using webpack alias and got the same error message.

Tried using webpack alias but still getting the same error message.

Comment: Down graded to non-beta webpack and it seems to work just fine; most likely a bug in tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin or webpack

Comment: It looks like it is a bug in webpack with my usage of # in the filename